# XMLResponse element show in list

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm doing a HttpWebrequest by using c#. I get the following response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Siri version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/">
  <ServiceDelivery>
    <ResponseTimestamp>2013-03-21T11:40:13.514Z</ResponseTimestamp>
    <StopMonitoringDelivery version="1.0">
      <ResponseTimestamp>2013-03-21T11:40:13.514Z</ResponseTimestamp>
      <RequestMessageRef>12345</RequestMessageRef>
      <MonitoredStopVisit>
        <RecordedAtTime>2013-03-21T11:40:13.514Z</RecordedAtTime>
        <MonitoringRef>020035811</MonitoringRef>
        <MonitoredVehicleJourney>
          <FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
            <DataFrameRef>-</DataFrameRef>
            <DatedVehicleJourneyRef>-</DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
          </FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
          <VehicleMode>bus</VehicleMode>
          <PublishedLineName>1</PublishedLineName>
          <DirectionName>Kempston</DirectionName>
          <OperatorRef>STB</OperatorRef>
          <MonitoredCall>
            <AimedDepartureTime>2013-03-21T11:41:00.000Z</AimedDepartureTime>
            <ExpectedDepartureTime>2013-03-21T11:44:27.000Z</ExpectedDepartureTime>
          </MonitoredCall>
        </MonitoredVehicleJourney>
      </MonitoredStopVisit>
    </StopMonitoringDelivery>
  </ServiceDelivery>
</Siri>
```

This response is saved in a string variable called "ResponseFromServer"
Now I just want to show  the 'ExpectedDepartureTime' in a listbox

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
//XMLResponse put in documentRoot
            XDocument documentRoot = XDocument.Parse(responseFromServer);

            //Linq To XML
            var documents =
            (from docs in documentRoot.Descendants("ServiceDelivery").Descendants("StopMonitoringDelivery").Descendants("MonitoredStopVisit").Descendants("MonitoredVehicleJourney").Descendants("MonitoredCall")
             select new
             {
                 dep = docs.Element("ExpectedDepartureTime").Value
             });
            //Show every ExpectedDepartureTime
            foreach (var i in documents)
            {
            lstHours.Items.Add(i);

                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
            }
```

When I try this nothing happens (the messagebox is not appearing and in the listbox i see nothnig). I also try to Descendant first the  tag without success...

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify namespace like this and then use one method `Descendants`

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.siri.org.uk/";

var documents = 
         documentRoot.Descendants(ns + "MonitoredCall")
                     .Select(x => x.Element(ns + "ExpectedDepartureTime").Value);
```

now you can

```
foreach (var i in documents)
{
      lstHours.Items.Add(i);

      MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

prints

```
2013-03-21T11:44:27.000Z
```

Comment: it turns out that using XPath with namespaces is a bit more convoluted than I suspected at first. It can be done but it's not as concise as your solution. +1

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your response. `LINQ to XML` is very good tool for processing xml.